# Склонение названия села Платошино

Tags: склонение, падежи

Склоняется ли название сёл Платошино, Калинино, Култаево?
Топонимы, которые заканчиваются на -О и на -Е не должны менять форму, ЕСЛИ ЕСТЬ РОДОВОЕ СЛОВО. Например: ученики школы села Платошино, из села Калинино, возле села Култаево.
Преподаватель утверждает, что раз село и название одного рода, то они склоняются. (Из села ПлатошинА). Действительно ли такая форма верна?

Answer (score 3):

Эти топонимы не склоняются: ***ученики школы села Платошино, из села Калинино, возле села Култаево.***

**Пояснение**

**Род** родового слова влияет на склоняемость: **название не склоняется**, если род  нарицательного слова и топонима **не совпадают.**

Но для топонимов на О/Е существует еще **дополнительное правило:** такие названия не склоняются, так как при склонении сложно будет восстановить исходную форму, например: поселок  Пушкин или Пушкино.

**Об этом говорится у Розенталя:** [§197. Приложения – географические названия](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_07).

**Об этом говорит и Грамота.ру**: [Как склонять географические названия?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=73)

Более того, такие названия обнаруживают **тенденцию к несклоняемости и при отсутствии родового названия.** Такой вариант допускается, но не в строгой литературной речи.

**Грамота.ру:** [**В ПРОСТОКВАШИНО ИЛИ В ПРОСТОКВАШИНЕ?**](http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_1_toponimy/)

**Азбучная истина № 1.**

Географические названия славянского происхождения, оканчивающиеся на *-ово, -ево, -ино, -ыно,* **не склоняются в сочетании с родовым словом**: из района Люблино, в сторону района Строгино, к району Митино, в городе Иваново, из деревни Простоквашино, до края Косово.

**Если же родового слова нет, то возможны оба варианта,** склоняемый (старый) и несклоняемый (новый): в Люблине и в Люблино, в сторону Строгина и в сторону Строгино, в Иванове и в Иваново, из Простоквашина и из Простоквашино, до Косова и до Косово, к Митину и к Митино, 8-й микрорайон Митина и 8-й микрорайон Митино.

При этом **склоняемый вариант соответствует строгой литературной норме.** Словарь Л. К. Граудиной, В. А. Ицковича, Л. П. Катлинской «Грамматическая правильность русской речи» указывает: «В образцовом литературном стиле (со сцены, с телеэкрана, в радиоречи) эти формы следует склонять».

Comment: Да, но раньше склоняли такие топонимы и с родовым словом, и мне это ближе.

Comment: Артем, я в ответе только цитирую источники., и они меня вполне устраивают. Сама  я такие названия не склоняю при наличии родового слова, а в некоторых случаях даже при его отсутствии. Например, есть два московских района: Ясенево и Строгино. При безударном окончании можно склонять  слово  в некоторых падежах (из Ясенева),  но при ударном окончании (из Строгино) я их не склоняю.  Из Строгина, в Строгине – такое произношение режет слух. Но это пока нестрогая литературная норма.

Comment: Ваш ответ хорош и был бы прекрасен, не случись (непонятно к чему) прописных букв на конце слов.

Comment: Это у меня окончания так выделены. Но если вас это расстраивает, то я их уберу.